# Arquivos CSS Internos/Externos não Carregam no meu Server Apache

Tags: php, html, css, apache, xampp

Estou utilizando XAMPP, meu sistema operacional é Windows.
Preciso desenvolver um sistema completo com bd, servidor, paginas da web e tudo mais, o que por si só já é um desafio pra mim já que nunca fiz algo tão grande.
Voltei a me deparar com um problema já tive muito anteriormente, mas que desta vez não dá mais para ignorar ou tentar "burlar", queria realmente conseguir resolver.

Quando adiciono um arquivo CSS por meio de um link interno, recebo o erro 404 no console de inspeção do navegador. Sou bem ignorante quanto a configuração e criação de servidores (inclusive se alguem puder me passar algum link onde eu ache informações mais detalhadas sobre desenvolvimento de servidores e como funcionam, aceito), o pouco que pesquisei a respeito me mostrou que o problema provavelmente esta na configuração do meu servidor.

Estou usando a configuração padrão do XAMPP, apenas escrevendo meus codigos como se fossem arquivos comuns, sem trabalhar com session, cookies e todas essas ferramentas de server (pois não entendo).

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />`

Alguem conseguiria me explicar de uma forma bem clara para um ignorante em Apache e servidores em geral, como eu configuro meu sistema para que ele compreenda e carregue minha tag de inclusão CSS?

[EDIT]

Tenho conseguido inserir meu css com a seguinte "gambiarra", mas acredito que tenha uma forma mais facil (e correta)

```php
<style type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <?php include('./css/index.css');   ?>
    </style>
```

Comment: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />'

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Se tu ta usando a configuração padrão era pra funcionar, deve ser problema de cache do seu navegador, pressiona CTRL+F5 ou CTRL+R, pra atualizar o cache do navegador principalmente se for o chrome, segundo você tá chamando corretamente os ids e as classes no css? pode ser isso também.

Outra no html 3 você não precisa mais especificar text/css, ele já reconhece automaticamente tanto o css quando o javascript.

Por ultimo muda o nome do arquivo css para style, estilo ou global, index e nome de página principal de site, o apache pode estar dando erro ai.

Links corretos para chamar o css:

> link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"

> link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/style.css"

> link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).